# Is there a way to load a config file to my custom Chromium browser?

Tags: c++, chromium

I'm developing my own chromium based browser. At the moment I'm using huge amount of data loaded with command-line into my Chromium. The reason why I chose to load the configs using cmd is the accessibility of data stored in memory directly and being available in any place of Chromium project. Unfortunately that's not enough because I'm going to load the presets of data taking up to 1 mb or even more.

Is there convenient way to load my configuration file into memory once at the program start so I can access it later same as command-line? Thnx for your further help!!!

I did my try loading config into Chrome prefs key value pairs but I did not manage it to work to load these prefs later

Comment: You can easily do that from the browser process. Maybe spend some time with the code base?

Comment: Yep, already passed data to local_storage 